# Should I use a company's letterhead on all of their files?

Tags: print-design, identity

I'm doing some design work for a company. I did a letterhead for them a while ago, and now I'm designing some forms that they will be providing to clientele to fill out. These are forms that will be printed and handed out in person to prospective clients to be filled out and returned on the spot.

Should these forms that I am designing be on the letterhead? Or is the letterhead pretty much for just *letters*. Is there some kind of "standard practice" for what a letterhead should be used for?

I ask because the letterhead takes up a bit of the page space, and I'll have to be economical with the form if I intend to put it on the letterhead.

Comment: What does the client want?

Comment: Most likely they'll defer to my opinion. I'm just wondering if there is any "standard practice" for this.

Comment: Well again, it depends on what the client wants or intends on how to do use them.  There is really no "best practice" because we don't know if the client is having you design web forms to send as a link, use them on a site contact form with a modal, print them out on the official letterhead you already made, plan on just sending a `.pdf` file with the forms you designed, official paperwork in a packet that would turn out redundant to have the letterhead on all the forms unless they are legal forms, etc. etc.

Comment: I've updated my question with the appropriate info.

Comment: Thanks for the edit but my point with everything is you are ultimately asking for a standard which is a valid question but I want you to be aware in the end it doesn't matter if the client has another idea for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes.**

In general, any materials which leave the clients' office should be branded, that includes forms. Some alteration from a letterhead may be required to fulfill the requirements of the form, but the same elements should be present - identity and contact information.

In some cases, I've designed two letterheads - A primary letterhead for most usage, then a secondary page with more attention to white space to allow more content on a page. Similar to the idea of a Home Page and a Seconary Page for web design.

Comment: What if the client says no?  I agree everything should retain a branding but how are we to suppose what a client wants or "their" standard of intent is?

Comment: I'd include in unless told otherwise. Branding is on my desk.. and as Pete commented, in most cases my recommendations are heard. After all they are paying me for my knowledge in that area.

Comment: Good point about "shells" though (preprinted letterhead to be used). But even if that were the case, my mock-ups would need to show the placement of the letterhead items and then those elements could be removed before production.